# Как сделать что бы z-index был больше чем у дочернего?

Tags: html, css, html5

Почему не получается посредством `z-index`, сделать так что бы текст выезжал из под полоски? Как видно на пример: тест поверх вертикальной линии!

```css
/** fadeInLeft **/

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -o-transform: translatex(-10px);
        transform: translatex(-10px);
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0);
        -o-transform: translatex(0);
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -o-transform: translatex(-10px);
        transform: translatex(-10px);
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0);
        -o-transform: translatex(0);
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(-100px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(-100px);
        -o-transform: translatex(-100px);
        transform: translatex(-100px);
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0);
        -o-transform: translatex(0);
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
}
.in-left {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.line {
    padding: 0 14px;
    border-left-width: 6px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #6dcd0e;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="line" style="z-index: 5;"><div class="in-left" style="z-index: 3;">текст выезжает под полоской</div></h2>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы `z-index` работал, нужно задать ещё и свойство `position` со значением *relative* или *absolute*.

```css
/** fadeInLeft **/

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translatex(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translatex(-10px);
    -o-transform: translatex(-10px);
    transform: translatex(-10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
    -moz-transform: translatex(0);
    -o-transform: translatex(0);
    transform: translatex(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translatex(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translatex(-10px);
    -o-transform: translatex(-10px);
    transform: translatex(-10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
    -moz-transform: translatex(0);
    -o-transform: translatex(0);
    transform: translatex(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translatex(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translatex(-100px);
    -o-transform: translatex(-100px);
    transform: translatex(-100px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
    -moz-transform: translatex(0);
    -o-transform: translatex(0);
    transform: translatex(0);
  }
}

.in-left {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  -o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.line {
  padding: 0 14px;
  border-left-width: 6px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: #6dcd0e;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.in-left {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="line">
  <div class="in-left">текст выезжает под полоской</div>
</h2>
```

Comment: Только об этом подумал!

Comment: А не подскажите как установить невидимость, что бы не было видно как текст ползет  перед полоской?

Comment: @AndSol: дополнил - `.line { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: просто красавчик!

Comment: @AndSol: спасибо. Это же основы. Удачи в изучении.

Comment: @UModeL Это не критика, а вопрос для себя - Нужно ли в настоящее время писать браузерные префиксы? Я понимаю, что они нужны для включения в браузер экспериментальных свойств CSS, которые стандартом ещё не утверждены

Comment: @Alexandr_TT:  в большинстве случаев, в настоящее время, префиксы это лишнее. Если не уверен в поддержке какого-либо свойства, лучше пересмотреть подход и использовать проверенные методы. Имхо.